# VB Function error message

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, user-defined-functions, vba

So I want to create a function to calculate the 'cost' of a solution to a problem.

I have created a 1 dimensional array Sum(m) that contains integer values. This is referenced in a different sub procedure.

```
Function Cost(sum As Integer, a As Integer) As Long

Dim total As Long

'Calculate cost
For m = 1 To 2 * n + 2
    total = total + (sum(m) - a) ^ 2
Next m
Cost = total

End Function
```

I'm not exactly sure as to what I should be using in the bracketed part of the line

```
Function Cost(sum As Integer, a As Integer) As Long
```

And when I try to call the function in my sub procedure, i get the error message - **Compile Error: Expected array**. This occurs in the line

```
SolCost = Cost(sum, UBound(x))
```

I'm really confused as to why this error is happening. It's probably down to a serious lack of experience with VB. Hopefully you guys can help me out.

If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is x? It is looking for x to be an array, it probably isn't, that is why it is throwing.

Comment: X(i,j) is already an array in the sub procedure. It forms an array of integers for which the cost is calculated. Basically, i'm creating a 'magic square'. X(i,j) forms an initial solution to the problem. The function calculate the cost of this initial solution (i.e, how far away it is from being a perfect magic square)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `UBound` a multi-dimensional array like that.  You must `UBound` one particular dimension of the array.  So if `X(i,j)` is your array, you must do either `UBound(X,1)` to signify the first dimension or `UBound(X,2)` for the second dimension.  This scales on to however many dimensions you have.  Take a look [at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_ubound.asp), their article covers multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Right ok, I'm going to head off to bed but i'll take a look tomorrow. Thanks for your help for now!

Comment: @Matt If this solves your problem, be sure to mark it as the solution.